# Centos installation

Tags: centos, system-installation

I want to install CentOS 6.4 on HP DL380 G4 server. First of all I select `install or upgrade an existing system`, but it boot something like without graphic (like basic video card). My main problem is in partitioning type: it shows this and won't let me custom partitioning:

```
                              |partitioning type|

installation require partitioning of your hard drive. the default layout is suitable 
for most users. select what space to use and which drive to use as the install layout


                          Use entire drive
                          Replace existing Linux system
                          Use free space

              [*] cciss/c0d0 .... MB (compaq amart arrey) 

                          OK                 BACK
```

I want to manually make the partitioning myself, but selecting each one of them don't let me to do that. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "Text mode installation Program". Anaconda also have a text-base installation apart of the graphical installation. If one of the following situation occurs the installation will use text-mode.

1. The installation system fails to identify the display hardware on your computer.
2. You choose the text mode installation from the boot menu.

I didn't choose text mode myself, I think the installation has failed to identify the display hardware because I use a KVM to use the server. There is some differences between graphical installation and text-mode (I don't know why there should be difference between them ). Differences are:

1. configuring advanced storage methods such as LVM, RAID, FCoE, zFCP, and iSCSI.
2. customizing the partition layout
3. customizing the boot loader layout
4. selecting packages during installation
5. configuring the installed system with first boot

[image: Centos installation menu]

for this problem i selected the second one (Install system with basic video card ) and the problem solved and the graphical installation came up with all options. I think in HP DL380 G4 the video card is weak or the installation can not recognize it so it use text-mode installation. but with basic video card my problem solved.

Some related information:
We can configure options that are not available in text-mode with boot options. see this [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ap-admin-options.html#sn-boot-options-installmethod).

Answer (score 0):

Select "Use Free Space". I hope you have free space on your HDD. I mean free space not on Drives, but on HDD.  If not, you have to create some free space on your HDD, by resizing your partition.

Comment: the problem is not free space this giant server have a lot of free space. i want to manually partition it but with this option its not  possible.

Comment: I believe if you choose `Use Entire Drive` that you'll get an option to change the partitoning at the next stage.  (I can't test at the moment, so tread carefully!)

Comment: i think, If you select "use entire drive" it will remove all others partitions. Go to the options and check.

Comment: @garethTheRed If I recall, that is correct. The next screen should allow you to "review" before committing. Then one can resize\do whatever they want.

Comment: choosing each one of them will not solve our problem. I answered it myself after bunch of search. thank you all